# Jquery json data not working

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following code

```
$(function(){
  displayRooms();
  editRoom();
});

function displayRooms(){
  $.getJSON("displayData.php", {action: "display"}, function(data){
     $.each(data.roomData, function(i, room){
        $("#display").append("<table><tr><td><a href='#?id=" + room.roomId + "'>Edit</a></td></tr></table>");
     }
  });
}

function editRoom(){
  $("#display a").click(function(){
    var roomid = $(this).attr("href").replace("#?id=","");
    $.getJSON("displayData.php", {action: "edit", roomid: roomid}, function(data){
     $.each(data.roomData, function(i, room){
       $("#roomType").val(room.roomType);
      });
    });
  });

}
```

My php file is correct and my sql statment is correct too but even though i can't make editRoom function execute. Can you please help me out?

Thanks!

I am posting the php function..

```
function displayData($dbh, $roomid){
  $data = array();
  $sql = "select roomtype from rooms where roomid = $roomid";
  try{
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
     $stmt->execute();

     while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)){
       $data[] = array('roomType' => $row[0]);
     }
     echo '{"roomData":' . json_encode($data) . '}';
      $stmt = null;
  }catch(PDOException $e){
       die($e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem here?  What does `displayData.php` return?  Should `data.rooData` be `data.roomData`?  Are you missing the `"` after `</table>` in your real code?

Comment: First of all, you have a missing closing quote `"` on the line that starts with: `$("#display").append(`...

Comment: Excuse any missing quotes or typing errors cause this is not a copy paste of my code.In my code there are no typing errors

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console? What do you mean by "i can't make editRoom function execute"?

Comment: This line is *incorrect*: `echo '{"roomData":' . json_encode($data) . '}';`!  This might create invalid JSON!  Do not manually create JSON, let `json_encode` do it for you.  Create the array structure how you want, then call `json_encode` *once*.  `echo json_encode(array('roomData' => $data));`.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat I will follow your advice, thank you for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) allows define only success callback.

Try something like this using [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
$.getJSON("displayData.php", {action: "display"})
    .done(function(data) {
       $.each(data.rooData, function i, room){
          $("#display").append("<table><tr><td><a href='#?id=" + room.roomId + "'>Edit</a></td></tr></table>");
       }
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert('error');
    })
    .always(function() {
       alert('Error or success');
    });
```

Comment: What are you saying?  `$.getJSON(url, {data: 123}, function(data){});` is 100% valid.  Why would using `.done()` help here?

Comment: You can write `$.getJSON(url, {data: 123}, function(data){}).fail(function() {alert('error');})` too, but it looks like a mess for me. If you want handle an error (and you should) using `done` and `fail` is much more readable.

Comment: @Boris Šuška, ok i change my getjson according to your comment, now it displays the error message.Is there anyway to find out what it is exactly?

Comment: @Antegeia: Yes.  In `.fail()`, there are some parameters passed.  Use those instead of just `'error'`: `console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);`.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that `editRoom()` is running before the JSON data is fetched. What you need to do is include `editRoom()` in the success callback in `displayRooms()`.

Comment: Or change the event handler bound in `editRoom()` to be delegated.

Comment: Can you please tell me how?

Comment: @Antegeia: Change `$("#display a").click(function(){` to `$('#display').on('click', 'a', function(){`.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat i change it but still not displaying any value.My sql is correct, i already execute it in phpmyadmin and returns some value.

Comment: @Antegeia: Do you see any errors in the console?  Scimonster is right.  `editRoom()` *is* running, but the event is not binding because it was called *before* the AJAX call in `displayRooms()` finished.  Are you sure `displayRooms()` worked?  Do you see your table displayed properly?  If you add `console.log()` lines to `editRoom()` do you see them?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: no i can;t see any errors in the console.